# JPA not loading collections with inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I have the following problem:
When I load a “HtmlPage” object the collection “tags” has always the size 0. The collection “parameter” works fine. The database also has the correct (I guess) entries.

### Here are my classes:

```
@IdClass(HtmlPageID.class)
@Entity
public class HtmlPage implements Serializable {


    /**
     * The parameters of this HTML page. (e.g. www.google.com/#q=test&tbas=0
     * will result in: q=test; tbase=0)
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "page", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private LinkedList<HttpParam> parameter;
    /**
     * A Collection of all  HTML tags.
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "htmlPage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<WebsiteTag> tags;

}

@IdClass(WebsiteTagID.class)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class WebsiteTag implements Serializable {


    /**
     * The name of the tag (e.g. div for the DIV tag).
     */
    @Id
    @Column(length = 2048)
    protected String tagName;
    /**
     * The associated HTML page.
     */
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    protected HtmlPage htmlPage;
}
```

If I use "@MappedSuperclass" in the abstract class (as I should) I get the following Exception:
 The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [null] and those of the entity bean class [class website.WebsiteTag] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.

```
public class WebsiteTagID implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The name of the tag (e.g. div for the DIV tag).
     */
    @Id
    @Column(length = 2048)
    protected String tagName;
    /**
     * The associated HTML page.
     */
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    protected HtmlPageID htmlPage; }
```

---

### Here are some entries from my database:

#### HTMLPAGE

COMPLETEPATH |  STATUS  | URL
/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/field-keywords=smartphone |   INFECTED    | www.amazon.com

#### WEBSITETAG

[EMPTY] I guess this should not be the case ??

#### IFRMAETAG

TAGNAME  | STATUS   | COMPLETEPATH  | URL
EMPTY 0.765217383991997 | INFECTED  | /s/ref=nb_sb_noss/field-keywords=smartphone   | www.amazon.com

---

### Here is one JPA query. If I execute this I get the results that I am looking for. But it is not added to the collection.

```
    [EL Finest]: query: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.834--ServerSession(23649981)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="tags" referenceClass=WebsiteTag sql="SELECT TAGNAME, STATUS, COMPLETEPATH, URL FROM WEBSITETAG WHERE ((URL = ?) AND ((STATUS = ?) AND (COMPLETEPATH = ?)))")
    [EL Finest]: query: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.844--ServerSession(23649981)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="tags" referenceClass=WebsiteTag )
    [EL Finest]: connection: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.844--ServerSession(23649981)--Connection(5106948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
    [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.844--ServerSession(23649981)--Connection(5106948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT TAGNAME, HREF, INLINKS, ISEXTERNAL, ISJAVASCRIPT, STATUS, COMPLETEPATH, URL FROM HYPERLINKTAG WHERE ((URL = ?) AND ((COMPLETEPATH = ?) AND (STATUS = ?)))
        bind => [www.amazon.com, INFECTED, /s/ref=nb_sb_noss/field-keywords=smartphone]

    [EL Finest]: connection: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.854--ServerSession(23649981)--Connection(5106948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
    [EL Finest]: query: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.854--ServerSession(23649981)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="tags" referenceClass=WebsiteTag )
    [EL Finest]: connection: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.854--ServerSession(23649981)--Connection(5106948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
    [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-30 16:28:57.864--ServerSession(23649981)--Connection(5106948)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT TAGNAME, HEIGHT, HEIGHTINP, INLINKS, ISEXTERNAL, ISJAVASCRIPT, SRC, WIDTH, WIDTHINP, STATUS, COMPLETEPATH, URL FROM IFRAMETAG WHERE ((URL
= ?) AND ((COMPLETEPATH = ?) AND (STATUS = ?)))
        bind => [www.amazon.com, INFECTED, /s/ref=nb_sb_noss/field-keywords=smartphone]
```

I really have no Idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

## EDIT 1

here some example code how I manage my Collections:

```
  public HtmlPage extracHtmlpage(Webpage page, String path, String htmlCode) throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        HtmlPage htmlPage = new HtmlPage(page, path, null, null)

        /*  Extract the GET Params */
        // If there is one '=' we know that there is at least one GET parameter with a value.
        if (path.contains("=")) {
            htmlPage.setParameter(this.extractGetParams(htmlPage, path));
        }
        /* Handle all the HTML tags.*/
        htmlPage.setTags(this.extractHtmlElements(htmlPage, htmlCode));
        htmlPage.setCompletePath(new URL(corrPath).getPath());
        return (htmlPage);
    }
```

and

```
private List<WebsiteTag> extractHtmlElements(HtmlPage htmlPage, String htmlCode) {
    List<WebsiteTag> tags = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<HyperLinkTag> links = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<IFrameTag> iFrames = new LinkedList<>();
    //Loop over all the html elements
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlCode);
    /*Handle links*/
    Elements rawLinks = doc.select("a");
    for (Element link : rawLinks) {
        HyperLinkTag ref = new HyperLinkTag(link.attr("href"), htmlPage);
           links.add(ref);

    }
    tags.addAll(links);
    /*Handle iframes*/
    Elements rawIFrames = doc.select("iframe");
    for (Element iFrame : rawIFrames) {
        IFrameTag tag = this.extractIFrameTag(iFrame, htmlPage);
        iFrames.add(tag);
   }
    tags.addAll(iFrames);
    return (tags);
}
```

and finally:

```
private IFrameTag extractIFrameTag(Element iFrame, HtmlPage page) {
        String width = iFrame.attr("width").replace("%", "").replace("px", "");
        boolean wP = iFrame.attr("width").contains("%");
        String height = iFrame.attr("height").replace("%", "").replace("px", "");
        boolean hP = iFrame.attr("height").contains("%");
        String src = iFrame.attr("src");

        IFrameTag tag = new IFrameTag(new Integer(width), wP,
                new Integer(height),hP, src, page);
        return (tag);
}
```

I don't see at which point this migth be inconsistent.

## EDIT 2

My DAO code is pretty straight forward

```
public void commitWebpage(HtmlPage page) {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(page);
        tx.commit();
}

public void updateHtmlPage(HtmlPage page) {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.merge(page);
    tx.commit();    
}
```

I persist/update like this:

```
   HtmlPage webpage = this.extracHtmlpage(page, path, htmlCode)
   insertData(webpage);
```

the insert code

```
public void insertData(HtmlPage website) {
    WebpageDAO dao = new WebpageDAO();
    if (dao.getWebpage(website) == null) {
        dao.commitWebpage(website);
    } else {
        dao.updateHtmlPage(website);
    }
}
```

What is not working is:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDataPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT w FROM Webpage w");
List<Webpage> results = (List<Webpage>) query.getResultList();
tx.commit();
```

In "results" I get my HtmlPages (yeah!) the collection "parameter" is there and has the correct values. But the collection "tags" has the size of 0 (buh!). The  HTMLPages has "tags" when I persist it.

Comment: You cannot mark WebsiteTag as a mappedSuperclass and then map to it using OneToMany because a mappedSuperclass isn't an entity.  It is just a bunch of mappings that get inherited by subclasses that are completely unrelated from a JPA perspective.  If you want to map to it, it needs to be an entity and its subclasses related through JPA inheritance.

Comment: Also, a mapped collection can't be of type LinkedList. You must use the interface: List.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to really tell what is going wrong, but I think you are making some wrong assumptions on some key points that are likely leading you to expect different (yet wrong) behavior.

First, mappedsuperclass is just a way to make some common mappings into a parent so they can be reused.  Any entities that extend from a mappedsuperclass really have no relation to each other (from a JPA/database perspective), so there really is no way to map to a mappedsuperclass; It just isn't an entity.

Now to table-per-class inheritance.  This means that each entity in the inheritance hierarchy will have its own table containing all the fields needed for an instance of that class to exist.  WEBSITETAG itself, since WebsiteTag  is abstract, should never have any data in it - and really doesn't even need to exist.  Any subclass of WebsiteTag will have its own table with all the same fields as WEBSITETAG and any parent entity classes they might extend, as well as any fields for additional mappings they may have.  An entity instance in this inheritance model will only ever have a single row in its corresponding table.  This differs from Joined table inheritance, where an IfrmaeTag entity instance will have a row in the WEBSITETAG table and a row in the IFRMAETAG, where the IFRMAETAG table only contains fields/data not in the WEBSITETAG table.  If you expect data to exist in the WEBSITETAG table, maybe that is the inheritance strategy you should be looking at.

As for the JPA query returning data  but the HtmlPage.tags collection being empty: this is common on bidirectional relationships where applications are making changes to only one side of the relationship.  JPA has a cache, and these plain java objects are not automatically adjusted for you when you make changes.  When you create a WebsiteTag and set its htmlPage, you also need to add that WebsiteTag to the HtmlPage's tags list.  If you do not, the collection will not show this change unless you force the HtmlPage to be reloaded from the database - either a refresh, clearing the cache or restarting the server.  It is usually much more efficient just to maintain your collection, but you could just call em.refresh(htmlPage) if needed.

Comment: I am using now Lists objects. Which doesn't change anything. The abstract class is a normal entity. Buy my problem ist stll there. I am also pretty sure, that my HtmlPage Objects are consitent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I am using now Lists objects".  Have you tried calling em.refresh(htmlPage) and then checking if your list is populated?

Comment: Ps my first two paragraphs were not meant to your specific problem, but in relation to some of the other questions and items visible in your post.  Specifically your question on if there should be data in the WEBSITETAG table.

Comment: calling em.refresh(htmlPage)  doesn't help.

Comment: Looks like you are setting new tags in the htmlPage, but you don't show what you are doing with the htmlPage object afterward.  Is the list populated correctly in the code you've shown?  Is it merged/persisted somehow?  Maybe we should take a step back - show the query code and exactly what is empty.